# MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor.execute returns different values in case of different cursors why?

Tags: python, cursor, mysql-python

See these two python code snippets,

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(c['host'], c['user'], c['password'], c['db'])
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from geo_weathers;)   ->  **1147L**
```

and

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(c['host'], c['user'], c['password'], c['db'], cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from geo_weathers")   ->  **18446744073709551615L**
```

Why the returned number of rows are different in above two cases ?
And just FYI there are 1147 rows in a table.

SSCursor is used for saving result at servers side. Is it the reason ?
What all rows are affected by this select query ?

Does anyone know ?

Answer (score 3):

The standard cursor used by MySQLdb is a stored result cursor.  This means that the entire result set is transferred from the server and cached in the client's memory as a result of the `execute()` call.

A `SSCursor` is a server side cursor will only return results to the client as they are requested.

The cursor `execute()` call will return the result of the MySql C API function [mysql_affected_rows()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) which in turn returns the result of [mysql_num_rows()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-num-rows.html) for `SELECT` queries.

Because results are stored server side, the client does not know how many rows have been affected until it iterates over the results.

The documentation for `mysql_num_rows()` says this:

> The use of mysql_num_rows() depends on whether you use
>   mysql_store_result() or mysql_use_result() to return the result set.
>   If you use mysql_store_result(), mysql_num_rows() may be called
>   immediately. If you use mysql_use_result(), mysql_num_rows() does not
>   return the correct value until all the rows in the result set have
>   been retrieved.

If you want to obtain a count of the number of rows, use `SELECT COUNT(*) from geo_weathers` rather than rely on the result of the `execute()` call.