# Get list of MySQL databases with python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to get the names of all databases associated with my MySQL server via python (2.7), but am instead just getting the number of databases.

I looked around, and it seems like the only answer may be to use `sys` for a command line call, get the name of the databases, and proceed from there, but I can't believe that's the only way.

**Current Code:**

```
import MySQLdb

serv = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "abcdefg")

c = serv.cursor()

print c.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try `print c.fetchall()` after you `execute`

Comment: @khelwood: Excellent, thank you!  I'm obviously a noob at this.  Also added `l = c.fetchall(); l = [ i[0] for i in l ]` as it was returning a tuple of tuples where the second item in the inner tuples was null - do you know why that would be?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551009/mysqldb-cursors-cursor-execute-returns-different-values-in-case-of-different-cur): execute returns the number of rows in the result in your context.

Comment: Each tuple is a row in the query results. I don't specifically know why the tuple would have a null (or `None`) in it.

Comment: @khelwood - Fair enough, thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure if mysql connector is same as your library, but using msyql connector your answer would be something like this:

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect (user='user', password='password',
                               host='server_address',buffered=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
databases = ("show databases")
cursor.execute(databases)
for (databases) in cursor:
     print databases[0]
```

Comment: For python 3 use print(databases[0])

Comment: Hi, is there an alternative to the for loop for viewing the databases. I inspected the cursor object but didn't found any trace of the databases. Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: If is not available mysql for python: `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Answer (score 1):

Just taking previous comments and reorganicing: 
**Current Code:**

```
import MySQLdb
serv = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "abcdefg")
c = serv.cursor()
print c.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
```

**With suggested modifications:**

```
import MySQLdb
serv = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "abcdefg")
c = serv.cursor()
c.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
l = c.fetchall()
print l
l = [ i[0] for i in l ]
print l
```

In my case the output looks like (*which is the desired output*):

```
(('information_schema',), ('data',), ('mysql',), ('performance_schema',), ('sys',))
['information_schema', 'data', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys']
```

Please note the following common error to prevent mistakes: if you try `c.execute("SHOW DATABASES").fetchall()` you will have an error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchall'`. This is way you should write firstly `c.execute("SHOW DATABASES")` and secondly `c.fetchall()`.

Comment: if you get an error, this suggests that your code doesn't answer the question and provide a solution?

Comment: True, it works, the last paragraphs is to point out a common mistake. (at least for me)

Comment: Ok. I think you could clarify the wording or formatting to make that easier to understand.